# Subfolder share permission on create over vbox (ubuntu host and ubuntu guest)

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, shared-folders

first time using ask ubuntu but kind of experienced user over here.

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 guest and Kubuntu 14.04 host using VirtualBox for some important testing, and am trying to use a shared folder from my host to my guest. I have already config the shared folder over VirtualBox machine config and also added the mount command on my Ubuntu guest `/etc/rc.local` file like this:

```
# On my guest machine
mount -t vboxsf my_shared_folder /home/myguestuser/Desktop/my_shared_folder
```

And also added my Ubuntu guest user to the `vboxsf` group:

```
# On my guest machine
sudo adduser myguestuser vboxsf
```

Now my host shared folder is actually visible from my guest desktop, but I couldn't write anything there from the guest machine because it was displayed as "root:root" owner:

```
# On my guest machine
myguestuser@VBoxMachine:~/Desktop/my_shared_folder > ls -l
total 1
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root 4096 jul  2 14:30 test
```

So I had to do something I hate to do, gave full access to everyone on my host shared folder (it is on another hard drive called `Data` but it is mounted as default on my host and also with my user as owner):

```
# On my host machine
sudo chmod 777 /media/me/Data/My\ Documents/Shared
```

So now I can see my shared folder contents on my guest machine and also write on it, BUT everytime I create a file or a folder from the guest machine, it is created with `drwxrwxr-x` access rights again.. :(

How can I keep the `777` access rights for every file I create from my guest machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my guest I only ever did the `sudo adduser myguestuser vboxsf`, installed guest additions, installed the extension pack and then added a shared folder via the VirtualBox GUI with automount and full access.  **Never** needed to do a `mount`.  The host is then available via `/media/sf_myguestuser` (or similar path).

Comment: Sorry for the really really really late response, I was well, busy XD. You were right, I reinstalled the whole virtual machine and tried again using VirtualBox GUI after adding my user to virtualbox users and bam! it worked! so it was probably the guest which was issued in some way :)